# The userAgent hook function of nextjs is not working

Tags: next.js

I'm using the `userAgent` hook as per the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server#useragent), but this doesn't seem to be working properly, I get `device` objects with properties that are all `undefiend`

`middleware.ts`

```js
import {NextResponse, userAgent} from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

  const { device } = userAgent(request)

  console.log(device)
  console.log(request.headers.get("user-agent"))

  return null
  // return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
}
```

Terminal output:

```
{ vendor: undefined, model: undefined, type: undefined }

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

My pages are basically client-rendered and not using SSR, but I guess that shouldn't be the cause of the problem?

Comment: try to import withou `type`:  `import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'`

Comment: @AhmedSbai I tried it just now, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the entire object returned from `userAgent`?

```js
const ua = userAgent(request)
console.log(ua)
```

If you take a look at the type of `userAgent`, it returns a `UserAgent` object which is guaranteed to have a `device` field but all the fields inside `device` are optional so they may not be available. Can you check if you get a valid value for other fields (e.g. `isBot`, `os`, `browser`)? Have you tried multiple devices, both mobile and laptop?